# How to Design Id Card ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey guys i am currently working in a project that needs a Resident ID Card to be printed.

The language used is `ASP.net`. Can anyone help me how to design ID Card for a resident that will contain *Resident image,name,mother name, address* and extra details....

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for your question. SO is **not** an "I need this; give me code" service. Please specify details of a particular problem you are experiencing and what you have done to try and solve it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question. In its current state - with no code, or specific details - your question is pretty much *asking* to get closed.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a html div for your Id Card design, print it using Javascript, what else you are looking for ?

Comment: This is more of a comment, rather than an answer. If you were intending to answer the question, please elaborate and extend your answer to include code samples or approaches which will point the OP in the right direction. Understandably, you currently don't have enough rep to post comments - if this is the case, please refrain from posting comments as answers; it is pretty much asking for downvotes and/or your answer to be deleted by moderators

Comment: yes i can understand, actually i did not have comment permission, so

Answer (score 0):

[Please see the above link for Designing](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_profile_card.asp)

just use repeater control it will create multiple ids.